# Case ambiguous column SQL - Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to clean up a field where there are extra text etc. I want them to return the quoted in the case but if they do not have these terms please use DIR column instead. The error I am getting says it is ambiguous. I am not sure what that means.

```
SELECT 
    L_Type, ALLE,
    CASE 
        WHEN ALLE LIKE '%F%'OR ALLE LIKE'%AS%' THEN 'EORCE'
        WHEN ALLE LIKE '%HOUR%'OR ALLE LIKE'%LE%' THEN 'U LEE'
        ELSE DIR
    END ALLEGCU
FROM  
    INC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AIO ON INC.INCNUM = AIO.INCNUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    S ON INC.INCNUM = S.INCNUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OFC ON AIO.OFFNUM = OFC.OFFNUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ALLEG ON AIO.AIO_NUM = ALLEG.AIO_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DIR ON ALLEG.DIRNUM = DIR.DIRNUM
WHERE 
    LINK_TYPE = 'Of'
    AND (INC.RECEIVED_DT >= {ts '2009-01-01 00:00:00'} 
    AND INC.RECEIVED_DT < {ts '2014-06-30 00:00:01'})
```

Comment: Can you please show your entire query.  Ambiguous columns generally mean you need to qualify them with the table name/alias...

Comment: @sgeddes, I have added the rest of my code. DIR is in the ALLEG table.

Comment: @sgeddes, THANK YOU, I QUALIFIED IT AND IT IS WORKING NOW

Comment: FIrst of all - get **rid** of all those unnecessary parenthesis `(` and `)` in the JOIN's - none of these are needed .....

Comment: Not really sure bout what you mean unnecessary parenthesis as I reviewed your edits and they are still there but thanks @marc_s

Comment: @epv: you don't need **any** parenthesis in the JOIN's - not needed, unnecessary, confusing .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the table name to your columns, like so:

```
select c.id, cc.name
from customer c
join customer_contact cc on c.id = cc.customer_id
```

By adding the table names or table alias you'll remove any ambiguity. Make sure to add it to all columns in your query.